# Change dt in SQLdatabase Copy past

Tags: sql, postgresql, dt

I have an SQL database where I need the copy rows

```
SELECT dt FROM public.data
WHERE dt > '2021-06-14 00:00:00' and dt < '2021-06-14 01:00:00'
```

These rows I would like to put in again but where all timestamps add 3 hours

How do I do this. I use PGadmin

Answer (score 0):

If you want to duplicate the rows with more recent timestamps, you would use `insert`:

```
insert into public.data (col1, col2, . . . , dt)
    select col1, col2, . . . , dt + interval '3 hour'
    from public.data;
```

Comment: I'm missing a little I can feel.

I've tried this: 

insert into public.data
SELECT *, dt+ interval '4 hour' FROM public.data 
WHERE dt > '2021-06-14 00:00:00' and dt < '2021-06-14 01:00:00'

I would like to include all columns

Comment: @Tage . . . You need to list them explicitly.